# Storing class in NSUserDefaults and accessing in next view

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I created a swift class called UserDetails and below is the structure:

```
import Foundation


class UserDetailsClass {
    var fullname: String!
    var mobile: String!
    var email: String!
    var password: String!
}
```

In my current View controller , I create an instance and store the values I want to move to next view in the instance variables as shown below:

```
var userDetailsInstance = UserDetailsClass()
            userDetailsInstance.fullname = fullNameTextField.text
            userDetailsInstance.mobile = mobileTextField.text
            userDetailsInstance.email = emailTextField.text
            userDetailsInstance.password = passwordTextField.text

            var prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            prefs.setObject(userDetailsInstance, forKey: "currentGuest")
            prefs.synchronize()
```

In the next view (where there is segue connected, I try to do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        var prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var userDetailsClass: AnyObject? = prefs.valueForKey("currentGuest")

    }
```

but the app immediately crashes. The objective here is that after user enters his/her details, i do not store them in server but rather in the NSUserDefault then take them to the next view where an SMS verification would take place. Once the verification is done, I would store the information on the server.

the error console is showing:

> Attempt to insert non-property list object appName.UserDetailsClass
>   for key currentGuest'

Is there a better way to move the data than storing an object in NSUserDefault?

I am a beginner iOS developer so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are unable to store the object in `NSUserDefaults` is because it is not a property list type (NSNumber, NSData, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, String, Bool). To store it in `NSUserDefaults`, it must be one of these types so you could serialize it to `NSData`, but in order to do that it would need to be `NSCoding` compliant.

The better solution is to pass the object in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: I tried that...but how would I trigger the prepareForSegue method when the button is pressed? I am checking for fields values etc inside the button pressed function. Need to do the same with segue.

Comment: It worked! just deleted the IBAction and copied its body to prepareSegue

Comment: This is a learning site. Can you post an edit to your original question showing what you did to solve your problem so others can learn from it?

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` doesn't support saving custom classes.
You should convert your `UserDetailsClass` to `Dictonary` and save dictionary to `NSUserDefaults`.